# neo4j can't create NEW relationships between existing nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

when I -

```
CREATE (c:Church{name: "Sts. Peter and Paul", address: "3745 S Paulina St Chicago IL 60609"})
```

and then I -

```
MATCH (p:Priest{name: "Fr. Thomas J OGorman" }), (c:Church {name: "Sts. Peter and Paul"})
MERGE (p)-[:POSTED {posting:1982-83}]->(c)
```

It works fine,

However, when I enter the identical statement, but change variables, like church, I then get (no changes, no records)
Tried creating indexes and variations which didn't help.

For instance:

```
MATCH (p:Priest {name:'Fr. Thomas J OGorman'}), (c:Church {name:'St  Barnabas'}) 
MERGE (p)-[:POSTED {posting:1977-82}]->(c)
```

I then get (no changes, no records)

Suggestions please? Thanks.

Comment: Can you PROFILE the query and add it here, with all elements expanded?

Comment: `'St  Barnabas'` contains *two* spaces. Perhaps you created the Church using a `name` value with only one space?

Comment: Spaces and syntax. Neo4j is a strict grammarian. Thanks for your help.